# Excel 365 Print Preview

Tags: vba, excel, printing, office365

I'm using Excel 365 on Windows 7 Home 64bit. When I open Print Preview from the Excel user interface I get a window  with options like this:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/132482128@N08/21711947524/in/dateposted-public/

From this window I can preview the whole print file, make adjustments to margins, select the printer to use, etc. I would like to access this window and these options from VBA. However when I use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").PrintOut Preview:=True
```

or:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").PrintPreview EnableChanges:=True
```

I get a window with options like this:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/132482128@N08/21713621773/in/dateposted-public/

I can only view the first page of the print file, and I am unable to change the printer. I have tried this:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
```

but it still does not bring up the modern Excel 365 PrintPreview dialogue and doesn't allow me to define what I want printed.

What am I doing wrong?
How do I get the new 365 type PrintPreview?

BTW - Using the .PrintPreview method in Word 365 VBA brings up the 365 PrintPreview dialogue, as you would expect.

Comment: I have dropped back to using "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").PrintOut Preview:=True". I could find no way of stopping the VBA running on, or controlling the "Print Active Sheets/Print Selection" option when using Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso". Also it gave the user too much access to the worksheets. Thanks Excel Hero. – RZB

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PrintPreviewAndPrint"
```

Reference: row 649 in this workbook:

http://excelhero.com/resource/excel2013ribboncontrolidentifiers.xlsx

Comment: Hmmm - I responded to this earlier today but it doesn't seem to have turned up! Opps - looks like the enter key posts it. Hmmm
Ahh - shift enter...
Anyway - Thank you so much for this solution...

Comment: @RZB Does this not answer your question?