# Excel print preview as File -> Print

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the printpreview from VBA (xlDialogPrintPreview) (See also: [Unable to add to ActiveWindow.SelectedWorksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639982/unable-to-add-to-activewindow-selectedworksheets))

When the preview is shown, i can not scroll to the next page. Well, actually i can scroll, but it does not show the next page. When I click on the page (zoom) after scrolling, it does show the right page.

This issue doesn't seem to exist when choosing File -> Print. I also like this screen better then the xlDialogPrintPreview. Is there any way to show this screen from VBA?

Comment: Is `.PrintOut Preview:=True` what you're looking for?

Comment: No, that will give you te same as .PrintPreview

Answer (score 0):

For the solution with the next page error; Just forgot to set

```
ScreenUpdating = True
```

For the newer print preview screen. I found the answer in another thread: [Excel 365 Print Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242291/excel-365-print-preview?rq=1)

This one did not come up in any searches, but found it through related threads on the left.